# Change BGcolor on input on hover, then back when mouseout, but if input has focus, disable the mouseout BGcolor change

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have an input, when someone hovers over the input I want it's BGcolor to change to gray, then when they hover off of the input I want it's BGcolor to change back to white(default color). But I also want the input's BGcolor to change to gray when there's focus on the input, but when the person has focus on the input, and then moves the cursor off of the input, the BGcolor will change back to white even if the input has focus. So basically I want the `mouseover` `mouseout` functionality to be disabled when the input box has focus, and then when it doesn't have focus anymore, re-enable the `mouseover` `mouseout` functionality.

Can anyone help me out? I'm not sure how to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, to detect whether an element has focus you might want to flag it somehow in its onfocus handler and clear the flag in its onblur handler. The 'flag' could take a number of forms, but a nice way of doing this in jQuery is to add/remove a class, which you can then check for elsewhere. For example:

```
$('input.trackingFocus').focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hasFocus');
});
$('input.trackingFocus').blur(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hasFocus');
})

$('input.trackingFocus').hover(
    function(){
        // do stuff on mouse in
    },
    function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('hasFocus')) {
            // do stuff on mouse out for elements with focus
        } else {
            // do stuff on mouse out for elements without focus
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using *only* CSS (why not keep it simple?), no need for JavaScript at all:

```
input { background: white; }
input:focus, input:hover { background: gray; }
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/4WX2G/1/).

If I'm following exactly what you say though, it would look like this in script (to completely disable the hover), you can do it using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), like this:

```
$("input").live("focus blur", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("focused");
});
$("input:not(.focused)").live("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).addClass("grayBG");
}).live("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("grayBG");
});
```

The last 2 handlers just won't act upon the element while it's focused (and has the `.focused` class).

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as having a filter on the jQuery collection before you alter the style:

```
$('#myinput').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).not(':focus').css(...);
});
```

Comment: You can't use the `:focus` selector like this, notice it's not listed in the API for many reasons, just like this: http://api.jquery.com/.

Comment: See this post http://forum.jquery.com/topic/focus-selector-filter. It states: "This works in ie6+, ff3+, chrome2+, saf4+, opera9+, both with and without qSA." The only drawback being FF2, Safari3 and Chrome1.

Comment: I don't think you read the post, `:focus` isn't a jQuery selector, in that forum post the user's **adding** it as a jQuery selector with `$.expr[':'].focus = function(a){ return (a == document.activeElement); }`, but since you're not running that code your example will work in a small fraction, if any, of those browsers.

Comment: Oh, my bad. It just happens to work in FF3.6 and I supposed it had been implemented since. Thanks Nick.